# Passing img src to another HTML page

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I´m new to web development and im trying to build a web-app using HTML, CSS and JS for the front-end and python along with flask for the back-end. I got some basic knowledge of HTML, CSS and python but both JS and Flask is new to me.

Anyway, im trying to create a page where you browse images, and once you click on one, i want to redirect to a new page showing that image along with some information. What i want to accomplish is very much alike https://pixabay.com/sv/.

Should this be done with JS or can it be done with Flask? And what is the "correct" and preferably easy way to do this?

Here is my code, my current problem is that i´m not sure how to send the img id. I only know POST and GET via forms. And how would i fetch the image based on the id in the server?

(The images are stored under /static folder)
app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, Response, redirect
import os


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/image/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def image(id):

    #fetch image based on id?
    return render_template('image.html', id=id)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<a href="/image/123">
    <img src="static/123.jpg" id="123" alt="" width="400" height="400">
</a>


{% endblock %}
```

image.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='{{ id }}') }}" id="123" alt="" width="400" height="400">

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: To answer your question we would need to know a little bit more, are you using flask to render these pages, or are you simply using it as an API? Frontend wise, you'd only use javascript if you needed to call an API then populate the image, you could simply redirect to that other page by using an "a" tag with the href attribute. Again, depending on how you are doing things it will change how you write your code.

Comment: Your question involves a frontend solution and a backend solution. The website you posted is using a backend with a database of images that load when the front page is loaded. When an image is clicked, it is queried most likely a database or some other form of an API then load's a new page. So yes, you may use FLASK or Node.js and build a website with a front-end and back-end system. It uses a URL query parameter to then load the page with the specified image. Multiple ways to go about this.

Comment: The "correct" way is to add an `id` parameter to each picture's link: `<a href="/image?id=abc">`. Not manually of course; the flask code that renders your gallery view uses the image's filename or database id to do that automatically. Next, in the "/image" route, flask reads the `id` param and uses that to pick the correct image to display.

Comment: The correct way of proceeding is to familiarize yourself with HTTP GET and POST parameters, and how they are used in links and forms. Try not to use *any* JavaScript yet. Once you know how to handle routes, parameters and POST requests bodies, i.e. the absolute basics of web dev, answers to questions like this will become obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! @dune184 If by render you mean using the render templace concept, yes, it´s new to me but im gonna give it a shot. For now the images are in the static folder in the env. I´m sorry if im not able to provide the best information regarding this but ye, i´m new and confused. And for the images location in the future, we have talked about a DB but will most likely keep in them in the web-server in some folder-structure.

Comment: @Simplyrdy cool, so what you should do, like others have suggested, is create a route in flask for @app.route("/image/<id>"), read that ID from the backend, and return a rendered page with the image's src set to the correct image based on that ID. On the main page you can just create a tags with hrefs to those individual images.

Comment: @ChrisG Yes thanks it´s something like that i´ve pictured it like, but as said im new to it and need to read more about this. I will try what you mentioned!

Comment: I´ve tried what you guys mentioned but i´m not sure HOW to accomplish it.